# RegularExpressionValidator fails if more than one character is entered

Tags: asp.net, regex

This my `asp:RegularExpressionValidator`

```
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" 
                runat="server" ControlToValidate="uxTrachoCtrl1"
                ErrorMessage="Ne dois pas contenir des caractères alphabétiques"  
                ValidationExpression="[0123456789,.<>=]" ValidationGroup="verification" Display="Dynamic" 
                SetFocusOnError="True">
            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The string can contain only those characters 0123456789,.<>=

This my regex [0123456789,.<,>,=]

It works if I type one character like f or 1, but if I put more than one character this will raise an error:

```
ex: input="1"=ok
    input="f"=error
    input="11"=error (It's supposed to be right)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The character class matches only one character. You need to repeat it if you want to allow arbitrary length characters:

```
"[0-9,.<>=]*"
```

If you want to exclude empty inputs use this instead:

```
"[0-9,.<>=]+"
```

Note that my character class is equivalent to yours (`0-9` is a shorthand notation for `0123456789` and you had the `,` multiple times in your character class).

Answer (score 0):

you just have defined the range of valid characters for one character

change it to

```
ValidationExpression="[0-9,.<>=]{minLength,maxlength}"
```

instead of `minLength` and `maxLength` you should put your desired numbers .
 or use `*|+` if you want to allow `0|1` or more repeat of characters as others suggested